# Prevent libvirtd from modifying file attributes

Tags: virtualbox, libvirt

I have a `.vdi` disk file that is shared between `libvirtd` and `VirtualBox`.

Each time I start a program with `libvirtd`, the owner of the `.vdi` file is set to root.

I'm wondering if it's configurable? I know it could be a security feature but I want it disabled.

**EDIT**

Running Arch Linux, up-to-date

```
libvirt 1.2.1-1
libvirt-glib 0.1.7-2
libvirt-python 1.2.1-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside the file `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` you'll notice this section:

```
# The user for QEMU processes run by the system instance. It can be
# specified as a user name or as a user id. The qemu driver will try to
# parse this value first as a name and then, if the name doesn't exist,
# as a user id.
#
# Since a sequence of digits is a valid user name, a leading plus sign
# can be used to ensure that a user id will not be interpreted as a user
# name.
#
# Some examples of valid values are:
#
#       user = "qemu"   # A user named "qemu"
#       user = "+0"     # Super user (uid=0)
#       user = "100"    # A user named "100" or a user with uid=100
#
#user = "root"

# The group for QEMU processes run by the system instance. It can be
# specified in a similar way to user.
#group = "root"
```

You can change the `user` and `group` to whatever you want so that `libvirtd` will stop stealing the ownership.

#### dynamic_ownership

There is another option that you may need to set in your `qemu.conf` file to disable `qemu` from changing the ownership of the `.img` files.

```
dynamic_ownership=0
```

This option was mentioned in this libvirt commit log: "[Don't chown qemu saved image back to root after save if dynamic_ownership=0](http://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=commit;h=a691cb88f2fa9d4caaca12ed048ed487fdbc09e3)". An example of this switch is availble in an actual [`qemu.conf`](https://forge.univention.org/svn/dev/branches/ucs-2.4/component/uvmm/univention-virtual-machine-manager-node/conffiles/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf), you can see the key section below:

```
# Whether libvirt should dynamically change file ownership
# to match the configured user/group above. Defaults to 1.
# Set to 0 to disable file ownership changes.
@!@
if configRegistry.get( 'uvmm/kvm/qemu/dynamic_ownership' ):
    if configRegistry.is_false( 'uvmm/kvm/qemu/dynamic_ownership' ):
        print 'dynamic_ownership = 0'
    else:
        print 'dynamic_ownership = 1'
else:
    print '#dynamic_ownership = 1'
@!@
```

#### References

- [Re: [libvirt-users] Stealing ownership: chown user->qemu->root](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2010-January/msg00020.html)

Comment: Does not seem to work, the VDI file is still owned by root .. Is there logs to check

Comment: @warl0ck - did something change or did you just get around to trying it and realized it didn't work now?

Comment: Sorry I just realized it didn't work ... my bad

Comment: @warl0ck - NP, I'll look around and see if I can figure out what's up.

Comment: @warl0ck - what about this? http://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=commit;h=a691cb88f2fa9d4caaca12ed048ed487fdbc09e3, `dynamic_ownership=0`.

Comment: @warl0ck - there's an example here: https://forge.univention.org/svn/dev/branches/ucs-2.4/component/uvmm/univention-virtual-machine-manager-node/conffiles/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

Comment: @warl0ck - glad to hear that I'll add that approach into my A.